# MVC4 RC WebApi parameter binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac, asp.net-web-api

I upgraded from MVC4 beta to RC and the latest autofac.  The following action was binding properly, but now both parameters are null.  I see they changed things about the Formatters and such but I am not sure what caused my problem

```
[HttpPost]    
RedirectModel MyAction(string value1, string value1)
```

REQUEST

```
Method: POST
Accept: application/json
URL: api/controller/myaction
BODY: {"value1":"1000", "value2":"foo"}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not really sure why the change from Beta, but I was able to make it work by changing the action signature to:

```
[HttpPost]    
RedirectModel MyAction(MyActionDTO dto)
```

and defining MyActionDTO as

```
 public class MyActionDTO 
 {
        public string value1 { get; set; }
        public string value2 { get; set; }
 }
```

It was throwing an exception about not being able to bind to multiple body parameters using the two string paramaters.  I guess using the DTO object more closely represents what you're sending in the AJAX call (a JSON object).

Comment: Adding [FromBody] to the parameters did not having any effect, the parameters were still null.

Comment: That does work, but I was hoping not to have to change it.  We do have a few calls that have a single string in the body.  I not sure why a single primitive types is required to be on the query string.

Comment: According to this:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx, you can pass one and only one item in the body.  So, if you want to pass a string value, you can do that, just pass the value without wrapping it as a JSON string.

Comment: asp.net site updated today with more info: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-1  Note you must prefix the value with an equal sign (=) when posting a simple value in the body

Comment: Thank you very much , binding parameters to C# class works fine for me .I want to ask why I can send parameters only to HttpPost WebApi actions , can I send parameters to HttpGet Web Api action ?

Comment: @OmarIsaid, a get request does not have a request body. But you can still send parameters in the url/query. It's just less suited for some cases.

Answer (score 20):

When you want to avoid using a DTO object, try this:

```
[HttpPost]    
RedirectModel MyAction(dynamic value1, dynamic value2) {
    string sValue1 = value1;
    string sValue2 = value2;
```

Comment: You are a hero.  This is the only viable solution in my very specific case.  I can't believe I didn't think of it before.  I wish I could give you additional upvotes.  Cheers.